# codeigniter age form

Tags: codeigniter

i want to make a sign up form where i get peoples birthday but can some one explain me how to make one?.

is there a function in codeigniter that do that :)?.

and then the user want to edit hes birthday how can i do so the day,month,year is selected to the current birthday :)?.

hope some one can help me out :)

Best regards Lena

Comment: CI is a *framework* - so this kind of feature isn't obtainable out of the box. As suggested, look at some of the existing auth libraries, but generally you'll need to code your own using CI's tools.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the available [Authentication](http://codeigniter.com/wiki/Category%3aLibraries%3a%3aAuthentication/) libraries. Most of them are open source and you could easily extend them to add the birthday information in the users table.